# Ionic change gradle version doesn’t work

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework

[image]

I got this error when running 'ionic run android'

What I did is change this line to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

as the terminal suggested. But it still has the error, and the file got reverted to

> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

still. Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

I think your gradle wrapper is set to 2.2.1. Check your build file.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
}
```

Make sure gradleVersion is set to 2.10.